# Possible bug in locking upvote on an edited question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, up-votes, locked

I'm pretty sure I just observed the following bug.  I up voted a question, it was then edited soon after, I waited a few minutes and decided to undo my upvote, but it refuses saying that my upvote was more than five minutes ago (which is true) and I must now wait until the question is edited before I would be allowed to undo the up vote (which is false since I'm pretty sure it was edited after I upvoted).

It seems to be a boundary condition not handled by the code, detecting an edit before five minutes have elapsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edits by the same user before the first 5 minutes of posting are not counted as edits.

So this is `by-design`

Comment: So perhaps it should keep you from voting until 5 minutes have elapsed?

Comment: I don't know @Wil, the spirit is that that edit never actually happened -- it's a grace period for you to fix spelling mistakes and the like, not to change the meaning of the post.