# can't upvote edited post

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, up-votes

(Related to [Possible bug in locking upvote on an edited question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66695/possible-bug-in-locking-upvote-on-an-edited-question) )

Order of events:

1. User X answered my question.
2. Answer sounded reasonable, so I upvoted.
3. Then I tried to use it, and got a compiler error, so I removed the upvote.
4. Several minutes later, (>5min, I think) User X edited answer to something else.
5. I wanted to upvote, but was locked out (can't find the error message to quote here, something like "you can't change your vote until the user edits it")
6. I couldn't upvote until User X edited the answer again, at my request.

The problem is step #5: The user *did* edit his answer, *after* I changed my initial vote. 
(There is a slight chance that my memory of the order of events is wrong, but I am not sure how to check this.)

The specific Q/A is here: [C++: constructor / initializer for array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221961/c-constructor-initializer-for-array/5222096#5222096)

Comment: +1 for a reasonable bug, but "no cookie!" for upvoting an answer without testing it

Comment: I agree (the "darn, I wish I had tested it before upvoting" thought came to mind), but I also think it's an unreasonably strict standard to test every answer before upvoting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked the data; step 3 occured about 9 minutes *after* step 4 -- i.e. you removed the upvote *after* the edit was made. So the behavior was indeed correct.

Comment: OK, thanks for checking. Darn! I hadn't seen the edited post when I removed the upvote.